# What do the adjust reasons in the BLE current time characteristic mean?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am implementing a CTS (current time service) synchronization method. [Here](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.current_time.xml) is the documentation on the current time characteristic (one of the characteristics in the CTS).

What do 'Manual time update' and 'External reference time update' mean, and what do they change on the device I am writing the current time on?

I have searched SO, WWW, and the Bluetooth SIG group but not found any further explanation than the names of those fields.

Comment: did you ever figure out any more information on the adjust reasons?

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to find out anything more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification document for Current Time Service defines these values (download pdf [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/current-time-service-1-1/) from bluetooth.com).

Specifically, section 3.1.2 Characteristic Behavior -- Notification:

> The server device shall set the Adjust Reason field in the Current Time to reflect the
> reason for the last adjustment of the local time on the server device.
>
> ...
>
> 3.1.2.1 Manual Time Update
>
> If the time information on the server device was set / changed manually,
> the “Manual Time Update” bit shall be set.
> Note: If the time zone or DST offset were changed manually, this bit shall also be set.
>
> 3.1.2.2 External Reference Time Update
>
> If the server device received time information from an
> external time reference source,
> the External Reference Time Update bit shall be set.
>
> 3.1.2.3 Change of Time Zone
>
> If the time information on the server device was set / adjusted
> because of change of time zone, the “Change of Time Zone” bit shall be set.
> Note: Following 3.1.2.1, if the time zone was changed manually the “Manual Time
> Update” bit will also be set.
>
> 3.1.2.4 Change of DST Offset
> If the time information on the server device was set / adjusted
> because of change of DST offset, the “Change of DST offset” bit shall be set.
> Note: Following 3.1.2.1, if the DST offset was changed manually, the “Manual Time
> Update” bit will also be set.